# Wrong URL generated from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Working on some javascript and I have this code which calls another php script on the same server.

```
function preLoadData()
{
alert("preload");
// Get the First Load of Data
$.ajax({
    url:"http://10.47.64.12:8080/Web/upload.php?get&interval="+interval,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'get',
}).done(function(data){

    // If we already have data update the labels on the web page
    updateLabels(data);
    for (var i in data) {
        labelLength++;
        var label = data[i].timekey.substring(11,16);
        var eventsDatasets = [];
        eventsDatasets.push(data[i].total);
        eventCount = 0;
        for (var title in events) {
            eventAtCurrentLabel = null;
            var ev = events[title];
            //console.log(title);
            for (var t in ev) {
                if (ev[t].start <= label && ev[t].end >= label) {
                    //console.log(title+" in label "+label);
                    eventAtCurrentLabel = -10-(eventCount*10);
                }
            }
            eventsDatasets.push(eventAtCurrentLabel);
            eventCount++;
        }
        // Best way of getting the data into the graphs | substring cuts the timestamp down
        totalChart.addData(eventsDatasets,label);
        trafficChart.addData([data[i].peoplein, -data[i].peopleout],data[i].timekey.substring(11,16));
    }
});
}
```

This generates a url that looks like this.

> http://10.47.64.12:8080/Web/upload.php?get&interval=900

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think thats correct. When I look at the console it shows that url with a 500 (internal server error). As well as errors in send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 and jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery1.10.2.js:8136

I'm working on someone else's code and I'm not sure what a correct url is, but when I run just that url on the upload.php script it stops right when it tries to prepare a PDO mysql query here:

> $get = $DBH->prepare($query);

Here is the portion of the PHP script that this ajax call is for:

```
elseif (isset($_GET['get'])){
echo "inside get ";
if (isset($_GET['interval']) && intval($_GET['interval'])) {
    $interval = intval($_GET['interval']);
}
else {
    // Default interval of 1 hour
    $interval = 3600;
}
echo $interval;
$query = "
            SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/".$interval.")*".$interval.") AS timekey,
            SUM(event) as movement,
            SUM(IF(event >0, event, 0)) as peoplein,
            SUM(IF(event < 0, ABS(event), 0)) as peopleout
            FROM     data
            WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE(NOW())
            GROUP BY timekey
            ORDER BY timekey ASC
        ";
echo " before prepare ";
$get = $DBH->prepare($query);
echo "before query ";
$get->execute();

if (!$get) {
    echo "Error: couldn't execute query. ".$get->errorCode();
    exit;
}

if ($get->fetchColumn() == 0) {
    echo "[]";
    exit;
}
```

Before this code it successfully connects to the mySQL database and I've tested the SQL query on the DB and it works successfully. What lead me to believe I was missing something in the ajax call was that the script just stops at the line here:

> $get = $DBH->prepare($query);

Comment: according to your code url is right. `http://10.47.64.12:8080/Web/upload.php?get&interval="+interval` is same as `http://10.47.64.12:8080/Web/upload.php?get&interval=900` . When you are getting interval before ajax call. otherwise `interval` will be undefined

Comment: Ok but the other parts of the ajax call, e.g. async: true etc.. Are those not supposed to be included in the url?

Comment: No, They are parameter for calling ajax. check this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Where is your labelLength defined?

Comment: Please share the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Ok I will, and the labelLength is defined at the top the my whole javascript code.